# How can I collapse spacing errors in plain text OCR output?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

Im looking for any advice on how I might approach collapsing spacing errors in plain text OCR output. Image below should illustrate the problem. Same problem repeats with pretty much every letter in alphabet. Lots of examples where a string like 'the giant dog jumped' as ' t h e g i a n t d o g j u m p e d'.

Regarding source data, this is a digitized historical newspaper so nonstandard fonts and printing practices give Tesseract a hard time.

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNCzI.png]

Comment: Without an example for a source image nobody can help you. What did you try until now? Which version of tesseract are you using? Which Options do you specify?

Comment: hi, there should be an imgur link to an image at bottom of question. does that help? unfortunately I am on the recieving end of vendor produced data so dont have ready access to tesseract parameters.

Comment: Yes, there is a link but it looks like the result, not the source image. If I understand you right, you do not have any influence on the OCR process? You just get the result and want to improve it? If yes than the OCR and tesseract tag is misleading and you will not get any answer this way.